# SQL - JOIN and SUB QUERY

Tags: sql

I would like two table to be joined

```
Table:  SignUp                                 Table: Thinker
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User_Id--+--Printer_Model--+--Product_No--+--Thinker_Id--+--Printer_Model--+--Product_No
1           HP OfficeJet 6480 C6615DN;CPT    8363           HP OfficeJet 6400 C6615DN;CPT
2           HP PSC 950        CB335WN;HEW    9436           HP PSC 950        CB335WN;HEW
```

And be able to receive a similar product that the customer has NOT already select but is required for the printer to operator.  In example, a customer makes a search for HP15Black, they will need the HP78 Tri-Color which will be on the left side of their web page. So I am trying to use the JOIN and Sub Query to != or <> the Product_No that they already have but find %LIKE% that will be displayed. This script below will bring up the same product and not a similar product.  Help...Jason Kraft - InksEtc  http://inks-etc.com

```
SELECT s.`User_Id`,s.`Username`,s.`Printer_Model`, s.`Product_No`,t.`Thinker_Id`,t.`Printer_Model`, t.`Product_No`
    FROM `Thinker2014` t
    RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT `User_Id`,`Brand`,`Username`,`Printer_Model`,`Product_No`
    FROM `SignUp`
    WHERE  `Brand` =
              (SELECT `Brand` FROM `SignUp` WHERE `User_Id`='1')
    AND  `Product_No` =
              (SELECT `Product_No` FROM `SignUp` WHERE `User_Id`='1')
    AND    `Printer_Model` =
              (SELECT `Printer_Model` FROM `SignUp` WHERE `User_Id`='1')
    ) AS s
    ON s.`Brand`=t.`Brand`
    GROUP BY s.Brand
    LIMIT 25
```

Comment: whats the problem with this query ??

Comment: Nothing...It's just NOT what I want.  I want Product_No "LIKE" what is being received and I keep getting what is inside the Table: SignUp and not all of the LIKE able Product_No that are inside the Table: Thinker

Comment: replace product_No =  with product_no like

Comment: O.K. I have done something like that but with AND Product_No !=

Comment: you could also use NOT LIKE

Comment: I just used the LIKE and I did get 1 answer...is there a way to get more than 1 answer :  )

Comment: may be you could try like with the brand and even the product model since both of them are strings ??

Comment: I received a different Product_No = CD995FN;HEW  Nice...BUT on a HP OfficeJet J6480 Printer there is a Black and a Tri-Color and an Original and Compatible which makes 4 Product_No.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rat-a-tat-a-tat, I would like to show you what I mean.  Goto:  inks-etc.com and goto the Login on the UPPER Right corner of the webpage

Comment: on the username: paul and password:2014 and confirmation password: 2014

Comment: Follow the Next Page button and you will notice that on the left side is just one extra ink cartridge that the customer may select that is similar to the one he/she has choosen

Comment: i saw the link, but may be you could check if the sentence case is making a difference?